# Simple web site on hostmonster

Tags: web, html, hostmonster

I have a domain registered and hosted at hostmonster.  I want to create a simple web site but don't really have the skills to pick out colors and backgrounds that would look good.  Does anybody know of any templates I can modify and upload create the site.

Thanks in advance, Paul

Comment: This isn't really the right site for your question; sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google will turn up a massive number of good results:

1. [Free Website Templates](http://www.freewebsitetemplates.com/)
2. [Free Site Templates](http://www.freesitetemplates.com/)
3. [Open Source Web Design](http://www.oswd.org/)
4. [Open Web Design](http://www.openwebdesign.org/)

Comment: I found a great template at Open Source Web Design.  Thanks Anthony